# What are the rules when differentiating tensor functions to the power of 2?

Tags: field-theory, tensor-calculus, conformal-field-theory

**How do I differentiate tensor squared functions?**

I know that, for example, to differentiate a function like $x^\rho x^\mu$ it is as follows:

$$\partial_\mu (x^\rho x^\mu) = \frac{\partial(x^\rho x^\mu)}{\partial x^\mu}=x^\rho $$

**But how do I differentiate something to the power of 2, e.g. $b^\rho x^2$ (where b is a constant)?**

---

*My train of thought is:*

in this case $b^\rho$ hasn't got a tensor $\mu$ so it can be ignored

$$\partial_\mu(b^\rho x^2) = b^\rho \partial_\mu(x^2) $$

$x^2= x_\mu x^\mu$ so we can differentiate , taking into consideration only the last term

$$b^\rho \partial_\mu (x^2) = b^\rho \frac{\partial (x_\mu x^\mu)}{\partial x^\mu } = b^\rho x_\mu$$

**I know this must be wrong because the answer to this example from my lecturer's notes is:**

$$\partial_\mu(b^\rho x^2)= 2b^\rho x_\mu -2b_\mu x^\rho$$

Comment: In your first equation, are repeated indeces supposed to be summed over? In this case you're computing a divergence, not a simple derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first equation is incorrect. It should be
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_\mu(x^\rho x^\mu) &= (\partial_\mu x^\rho) x^\mu + x^\rho (\partial_\mu x^\mu)\\&=
\delta_\mu^\rho x^\mu + x^\rho \delta^\mu_\mu \\&= x^\rho + x^\rho\,d \\&= (d+1)\,x^\rho\,.
\end{aligned}
$$
When you have $x^2$ use $x^2 = x^\rho x_\rho$ and simply use the rule for products. Remeber to use a new index, not one that already appears somewhere else in the expression.
$$
\partial_\mu x^2 = \partial_\mu x^\rho x_\rho = \delta^\rho_\mu x_\rho +\eta_{\mu\rho} x^\rho= 2 x_\mu\,.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought I could just ignore any term whose tensor didn't match the one being taken into consideration for differentiation.

Comment: You cannot because $x^\rho$ and $x^\mu$ are not different variables. They are different when $\mu \neq \rho$ and they are the same when $\mu = \rho$. And your final expression should account for both cases.